# Which RxJS Observable operator to achieve lazy/dynamic forkJoin behaviour

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, angular2-observables

I'm looking for a way to chain RxJS Observables to achieve the following steps in an Angular app:

1. Create Gallery entity on backend server
2. Upload photos as they are taken
3. Update Gallery entity on backend server with timestamp
4. Update page with results

I have an Observable `photoObservable` that encapsulates the camera component that completes when the camera component is closed.

Here is a snippet of the code I have so far. The Observable chain in the middle is where I'm struggling:

```
    private photoObservable: Observable;
    private photoObserver: Observer;

    cameraClosed() {
      this.photoObserver.complete();
    }

    uploadPhotoFromCamera(data) {
      if (this.photoObservable == null) {

        this.photoObservable = new Observable((observer) => {
          this.photoObserver = observer;
        });

        this.galleryService.putGallery(...)
        .mergeMap(
          returnedGallery => {
            // This where I need to upload photos as they are taken
            // Each upload will return an Observable
          })
        .concatMap(
          returnedGallery => {
            this.galleryService.updateGallery(returnedGallery));
          }
        .subscribe(
          returnedGallery => {
            log('Gallery updated!');
          );
      }
      this.photoObserver.next(data);
    }
```

I've tried concat and concatMap as they both rely on the previous Observable completing before the next is run, but I can't get it to work.

Is there a way of achieving this using RxJS operators? Some kind of mix between a concat and a forkjoin maybe?

Comment: Do you mean something like merge ? http://rxmarbles.com/#merge

Comment: What is the purpose of `photoObservable`? And do you get one or mulitple observables at a time at `// This where I need to upload photos as they are taken`

Comment: `photoObservable` represents the camera component. Each time a photo is taken, it's `next ()` method is called with the photo data. When the camera component is closed, it's `complete()` method is called. The idea being that at that point, the gallery can be updated with a timestamp (and some other jobs are kicked off server side to handle the batch of photos).

Comment: I don't think merge would do it. I need to wait for a batch of observables to complete before kicking off the next one.